# Multiple Images in with Python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Just started with Python PIL and I wondered if you can make more than one image at a time on the same line of code?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want? `Image.new('RGB', size).split()` will generate 3 images, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: You could make a list of them with a list comprehension for example. What exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: I want to make five different color images(red, blue, yellow, white, green), name them red.gif, blue,gif, yellow,gif, white,gif, green,gif and then save them to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you could get using tuples to assign multiple variables at once:

```
(img1, img2, img3) = (Image.new('RGBA', (100, 100), (255, 255, 255, 255)), Image.new('RGBA', (200, 50), (255, 255, 255, 255)), Image.new('RGBA', (50, 350), (255, 175, 255, 255)))
```

Comment: But it's worth adding it'd be much more readable and less prone to bugs with three lines of code.

Comment: I agree, It's only in rare cases that you'd need to use this